# How to add a dynamic select field in woocommerce product page

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I have a custom post type `fine_prints` with only a title field.

I want to **add** a new field in `woocommerce product page`. A dynamic select that will show all `fine_prints` with their `id` as `value`. I have added many custom fields in `product page` using `ACF`. I'm new to wordpress. How can I achieve this? Any help? I want to do this in `functions.php`. Thankyou.

Comment: its possible to do it using ACF, why you are going for custom code in functions.php ?

Comment: How can I achieve it using ACF? I have the free version. Can you please guide me @daniyalahmad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For adding select custom filed for custom post type in AC, follow

1. Select Filed type "Post Object"
2. Select "Post type"

It will return an array so you can loop through it.

[image]